# Get google Map Location and distance

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, google-maps, maps

I am creating a project on carpooling website.Now I want to add a google map on my website project.When user click on a particular location then the name of the location automatically filled in Source text field and on selecting again the destination textbox filled with the name of location.And than the distance of these two location calculated.
Is this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

so that you can place google maps in your website. and use javascript event handlers to get location details when you click somewhere in map.